# Run Git console in TotalCommander by key shortcut

Tags: windows, git, keyboard-shortcuts, git-bash, total-commander

It is possible to run GIT bash console starting in current folder in Explorer or TotalCommander? I use Win 10.

For example: I use TotalCommander or standard WinExplorer, I'm in path c:\src\MyProjekt (there is git repo), I press specified key combination and I can type git command.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like that works for me for Total Commander (but it's not perfect):

1. Run Total Commander and choose from top menu Start/Change Start Menu.
2. Add new item with name like *Git Bash* as:

   a) command: `c:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe --login`
   b) shortcut key: `ctrl+alt+f1` (to choose from list).
3. Click OK.

Since now pressing `ctrl+alt+f1` should run Git Bash in current folder.

Another option (which I usually use) is to run this from Context menu:

1. Context menu key/Shift-F10
2. A few cursor down presses (depends on tool which I want to run).
3. Enter.

This should work also for Windows Explorer and anything else.
It's not a shortcut, but still a keyboard.

Comment: Thanks, great answer, for some reason `ctrl+alt+f1` did nothing but `shift+ctrl+alt+f1` worked. Maybe it will be useful for someone.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks! I use `Shift+F10` and then `s` (for `Git Bash here`) from now on.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me without adding *--login* after the path, as the application *(git-bash.exe)* already adds it:

[image: Git Bash at startup]